# How can I create "if" and "else if" for several time in onedit_function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please, help to solve the problem. In googlesheets scripts. Need to make several "if" while editing a range.
This code works well, but it's about only editing range. But I need to add a condition when another range in the same row has the definite value.

I have: 5 lists (List1, list2, name1, name2, name3)
I need: (always: copy values from list1 to list2 with "onedit", not always: and only if another range in this row has name1 or 2 or 3, copying is going to that sheets respectively.

if edited range is TRUE
copy to list2
and `if range.offset(0,10).getvalue == "Name1"`
copy to list "Name1",
and `if range.offset(0,10).getvalue == "Name2"`
copy to list "Name2"
and `if range.offset(0,10).getvalue == "Name3"`
copy to list "Name3"

This works only for the first step, of course...

```
function onEdit(e) {
    const range = e.range; //edited range
    const value = e.value; //value
    const ss = e.source; //tabl
    const sheet_from = ss.getActiveSheet(); //activelist

    if (sheet_from.getName() == 'List1' && range.getColumn() == 1 && value == 'TRUE') { //условие запуска переноса строки

        const sheet_to = ss.getSheetByName('List2'); 
        const row = range.getRow(); //active row
        const row_values = sheet_from.getRange(row, 2, 1, 1).getValues(); 
        const sheet_to_lr = sheet_to.getLastRow(); 

        sheet_to
          .getRange(sheet_to_lr+1, 2, 1, 1)
          .setValues(row_values); 
    }
}
```

Comment: So, did you get a solution, after all?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range; //edited range
  const value = e.value; //value
  const ss = e.source; //tabl
  const sheet_from = ss.getActiveSheet(); //activelist

  if (sheet_from.getName() != 'List1') return;
  if (range.getColumn() != 1) return;
  if (value != 'TRUE') return;

  let sheet_to = ss.getSheetByName('List2');
  const row = range.getRow(); //active row
  const row_values = sheet_from.getRange(row, 2, 1, 1).getValues();
  let sheet_to_lr = sheet_to.getLastRow();

  sheet_to.getRange(sheet_to_lr + 1, 2, 1, 1).setValues(row_values);

  const next_cell = range.getCell(1, 1).offset(0, 2).getValue();

  if (next_cell == 'Name1') {
    sheet_to = ss.getSheetByName('Name1');
    sheet_to_lr = sheet_to.getLastRow();
    sheet_to.getRange(sheet_to_lr + 1, 2, 1, 1).setValues(row_values);
  }

  if (next_cell == 'Name2') {
    sheet_to = ss.getSheetByName('Name2');
    sheet_to_lr = sheet_to.getLastRow();
    sheet_to.getRange(sheet_to_lr + 1, 2, 1, 1).setValues(row_values);
  }

}
```

`range.getCell(1, 1).offset(0, 2).getValue()` this way you can get a value of the 10th cell of the same row.

Then you can check the value and perform any actions.